# Combining child class lists to parent class list

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have a parent class X and two lists of child classes X1 and X2 (X1 and X2 derive from X). Is there an easy way to combine the lists of X1 and X2 into a list of Xs?
I could loop over the lists of X1 and X2 and add then to the list of X but this seems a bit cumbersome.

Comment: you can use cast i guess

Comment: sure but that requires looping. I am looking for a linq (less code) solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQ can do this conveniently with

```
var both = list1.Cast<X>().Concat(list2.Cast<X>()).ToList();
```

or with

```
var both = ((IEnumerable<X>)list1).Concat((IEnumerable<X>)list2).ToList();
```

but it's looping nonetheless -- just under the covers.

Comment: don't really care about looping as long as I do not have to write too much code (-: just came across ConvertAll as well

Answer (score 2):

Use [Enumerable.Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb341406.aspx) Method, like this:

```
var list1 = new List<X1>();
var list2 = new List<X2>();
var result = list1.Cast<X>().Concat(list2.Cast<X>()).ToList();
```